# SMS archiving and control

Tags: sms, file-archives

I've searched throughout the web with no joy. My background: I've got 16+ years in software (I'm out of it but not before I built some Android apps for myself).

My problem is that I'd like to reduce the amount of space used on my phone for old messages but I'd like to keep them available.

Something like an automated system that prunes old messages to off-site (cloud) storage but makes them available upon demand.

What I want, is a system that lets me keep my chats growing indefinitely while keeping only a specified amount of space used on the phone.

Thoughts?  Suggestions?

Comment: sms database is growing regardless deleted messages. if you export all messages, delete database and import back, the size is reduzed. you can do it manually with MyPhoneExplorer

Answer (score 0):

2 options come to mind.

- Export sms to text file and upload the text file to a cloud service.
  In your application, you would need to recognize when the user wants to load older messages, maybe an onScroll event or maybe a "Load More" button etc...
- Store SMS entirely on cloud services.
  Only load the sms from a cloud, and upload whenever you receive a message.
  The application purely loads the sms list as a ListView from the content returned by the server.

Using PHP and SQL as the server API would work to build your own server.